# "ValueError: _system not initialized" when using apt.VersionCompare

Tags: apt, python

I wrote a bash script that has to compare two version strings to decide to download new version or not.
The test relies on a Python script that does `apt.VersionCompare()`, which does version comparison the way `apt` does.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, apt
res = apt.VersionCompare(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
if res < 0:
   sys.exit(-1)
if res > 0:
   sys.exit(1)
sys.exit(0)
```

With upgrade to Ubuntu 14.4 this stopped working.

I tried to change the script following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957514/ as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, apt_pkg
res = apt_pkg.version_compare(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
if res < 0:
   sys.exit(-1)
if res > 0:
   sys.exit(1)
sys.exit(0)
```

but this gives me  `ValueError: _system not initialized`. How to solve, or is there a better way to compare versions like `apt` does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely the code works when I run it from an interactive Python prompt. At any rate, this [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=369147) points to a solution(?)<sup>1</sup>:

Add a call to `apt_pkg.init_system()` as documented [here](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#module-initialization) (or do `import apt` as well):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, apt_pkg
apt_pkg.init_system()
res = apt_pkg.version_compare(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
if res < 0:
    sys.exit(-1)
if res > 0:
    sys.exit(1)
sys.exit(0)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Apparently the `InitSystem` function name has changed too, from CamelCase to using underscores.

Comment: did you happen to do an `import apt` at the interactive prompt before importing `apt_pkg`? That would explain things, as that initialises the module as well.

Comment: @Anthon I checked my python3 history, doesn't look like it. But now in a python shell I get that error. O.o

Comment: @Anthon - thanks for the hint! Without first importing `apt` in my script, `apt_pkg` was not working properly (even after running `apt_pkg.init_system()`).

Comment: FWIW you can skip importing `apt` if you call `apt_pkg.init_config()` and then `apt_pkg.init_system()`. `init_config()` isn't needed for all methods (hence why this post works without it), but it is for most apparently.